# Excel macro not triggering on cell change

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro which previously triggered on a cell change but for some reason now it fails to trigger. I'm not sure what has changed to have caused this. All the macro has to do is refresh 4 pivots, which can be done manually no problem.

I've tried different ways of setting up a macro to trigger on a cell change, however they all fail to trigger on cell change.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim KeyCells As Range

    Set KeyCells = Range("V76:W76")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then

    Sheets("NATFLOW").PivotTables("PivotTableA2").PivotCache.Refresh
    Sheets("NATFLOW").PivotTables("PivotTableB2").PivotCache.Refresh

    Sheets("NATTABLE").PivotTables("PivotTableAlpha2").PivotCache.Refresh
    Sheets("NATTABLE").PivotTables("PivotTableBeta2").PivotCache.Refresh

    End If

End Sub
```

The outcome is that nothing happens, including no error messages.

Comment: Your code seems like it should work fine. Is there any other code involved in your project? Reason I'm asking, there might have been a `Application.EnableEvents = False` applied. Try running a piece of code to turn this to `True` to see if your event triggers like it should.

Comment: I tried your code on My System. It works fine.

Comment: By cell change you mean a cell updated by a formula? This event won't trigger in this case.

Comment: Thanks guys, it turns out it was VBA not installed on my system due to Windows having been re-installed while I was away. Sorry for the false alarm, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @gabriel can I suggest you delete this question,  since it's root cause is unrelated to anything mentioned in the Q.

Answer (score 1):

If nothing happends, including no error messages, so is due to this `Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address))` equals `nothing`.

Try to run step by step and check if the value of `Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address))`

Comment: Sorry for the false alarm, it turns out VBA wasn't installed on my machine so macros weren't running. Your help much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

'Method 1 - Specific sheet, specific objects
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("V76:W76")) Is Nothing And Target.Count = 1 Then

        With Sheets("NATFLOW")

            .PivotTables("PivotTableA2").PivotCache.Refresh
            .PivotTables("PivotTableB2").PivotCache.Refresh

            .PivotTables("PivotTableAlpha2").PivotCache.Refresh
            .PivotTables("PivotTableBeta2").PivotCache.Refresh

        End With

    End If

End Sub

'Method 2 - Refresh everyting from this workbook
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("V76:W76")) Is Nothing And Target.Count = 1 Then

        ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll

    End If

End Sub
```